# iPhone user history database (SQLite? Core-Data?)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data, nsstring

In my iPhone app the user can choose from a large list of audio on demand programs available on a website, sorted by speakers, programs names and days of the week.

I'd like the app to have a history of the most recent heard programs, so the user can keep track of what he has already listened to, including the date and time of accesses.

When the user is in the final stage of his choices I have three resulting NSStrings available in memory:

NSString *program;
NSString *speakerName;
NSString *weekDay;

How can I build a database, a history access, storing these 3 strings (plus date, time and how many minutes the audio has been played) every time the user listens to a different audio file so he can have a list of his played programs?

I'm reading about SQLite and Core Data for the iPhone but I'm not certain if that's the way to go, since I'll have just a few elements to save each time on a database.

Does anyone know of a sample xCode project for doing that? What should I study to accomplish this task?

Any suggestions/guidelines will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something this simple, you should use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Basically, NSUserDefaults gives you a dictionary into which you can put NSStrings, NSDates, NSNumbers, or NSDictionarys or NSArrays of these objects. To use it you do something like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myString forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Then later, you can access the value by doing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try it and will let you know. Questions: does it hold the data as long as the app is installed? Can it hold like the last 5 heard audio programs or just the very last one? Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: User Defaults are preserved as long as the app is installed, yes. So deleting the app from the device would clear them. You can also clear them programmatically by setting the values to nil. User Defaults might get backed up with the device backups…I think they probably are, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that will do for now, since it just will only store the last access as it overwrites the previous one.